# AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'celery'

Tags: docker, celery, django-celery

I want to use celery in my Django app for a task that should run in the background. I've followed these tutorials [Asynchronous Tasks With Django and Celery](https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/) and [First steps with Django Using Celery with Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

my project structure:

```
project
├──project
|  ├── settings
|     ├──__init__.py   (empty)
|     ├──base.py
|     ├──development.py
|     └──production.py
|  ├──__init__.py
|  └──celery.py
├──app_number_1
|  └──tasks.py
```

project/project/**init**.py :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

project/project/celery.py :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings.production')

app = Celery('project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

project/project/settings/production.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'background_task',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
]
.
.
.
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'mongodb://mongo:27017'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'mongodb://mongo:27017'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    env_file:
      - env_vars.env
    build: .
    restart: always
    command:
      - /code/runserver.sh
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - mongo

  db:
    ...

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
```

runserver.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
python3 /code/project/manage.py migrate --settings=project.settings.production
python3 /code/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=project.settings.production & celery -A project worker -Q celery
```

after `docker-compose up --build` I get the following error:

```
web_1    | Running migrations:
web_1    |   No migrations to apply.
mongo_1  | 2019-08-28T10:24:26.478+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 172.18.0.4:42252 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | 2019-08-28T10:24:26.479+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 172.18.0.4:42250 (0 connections now open)
web_1    | Error: 
web_1    | Unable to load celery application.
web_1    | Module 'project' has no attribute 'celery'
```

any hint will be great!

thanks

Comment: Does it work outside docker ?

Comment: Note that while it may not be the cause of your issue, having two nested directories named "project" is confusing at best.

Comment: Also, having both a 'settings.py' module and a 'settings/' subpackage at the same level doesn't help either (the subpackage shadows the module IIRC but that's still very confusing)

Comment: the real name is not "project" Bruno ...

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the naming of the file, since celery.py will have a naming conflict with celery itself. Try changing that file name and see if that works.

Comment: Your `project` package needs to be in the PYTHONPATH for the code to work.

Comment: @Moein well, fine, but you didn't answer the important question: __does it work outside docker ?__  If not, please post the full traceback. ATM we don't have enough information to emit anything else than wild guesses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The celery module isn't contained in the first project folder.

You can either move it there or make project into a package by adding an __init__ module and setting the app instance module in the celery command to be:

```
celery -A project.project worker -Q celery
```

Comment: thanks for the help it worked.
in celery -A <name> command <name> should contain celery.py