# Module 'project_name' has no attribute 'celery'

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to set up a background task using celery and rabbitmq on django but I'm getting an error saying that my project has no attribute celery. I'm using PyCharm and installed celery through that.

I'm new to celery but I've read a lot of articles similar to this issue ([AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'celery'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690681/attributeerror-module-module-has-no-attribute-celery) this one seems the closest but not sure it's quite the same)

Project structure:

```
project_name
├──project_name
|  ├── settings.py
├──app_name1
|  └──celery.py
├──app_name2
|  └──tasks.py
```

I run the following command:

```
celery -A project_name worker -l info --pool=solo
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid value for "-A" / "--app":
Unable to load celery application.
Module 'project_name' has no attribute 'celery'
```

celery.py file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings')

app = Celery('project_name')

app.config_from_object('django.config:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

tasks.py file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: Try to put `celery.py` file into the main project file, not inside the app

Comment: Thanks, I think that has worked. It's moved me on to a new error at least! No module named 'django.config' but I'll start searching on that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record: Put `celery.py` file into the main project file, not inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter into the project via the terminal. Write:

```
cd project_name
```

It worked with me